# Sending the HL message from dot net application to mirth connect

Tags: asp.net, .net, tcp, hl7, mirth

I want  to connect Mirth  application to our dot net application  to  send HL7 message.I am using windows 7 32 Bit  and mirth v 3.4.2.8129 .  I have connected the mirth application  using TCP and Port Number but when we send the data to mirth connect then its not visible in  mirth connect  and also does not show any error in connectivity Please tell me required setting to be done in Mirth connect and our Dot net application

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to config your .net app to use MLLP for HL7 .  I'm not sure how to do that.  Then configure Mirth Connect as a TCP listener as source.

Answer (score 0):

When sending TCP/IP messages make sure your message contains the proper HL7 Transports otherwise Mirth might think the message isn't complete and is listening for more data. Make sure the message has a vertical tab (0x0B) before the MSH Segment followed by a trailing field separator (0x1C) and carriage return (0x0D) after the last segment.